# AndroidManifest "app_banner" issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, banner

i just want  to add banner to mygame but when i build my game,i face to this bug in unity console.

*AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'banner' with value '@drawable/app_banner'*).

You can find my AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity.package" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <!--

      The unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik flag is the only difference
      from Unity's auto-generated default AndroidManifest.xml. We require this
      flag to be true for ads to be clickable.

      If you are using another plugin that also ships with an
      Assets/Plugins/AndroidManifest.xml, you can use their copy after setting
      this flag to true.

      -->
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: what files are in your res/drawable folder?

Comment: Only 4 files @FredGrott  ;
common_signin_btn_icon_dark;
common_signin_btn_icon_light;
common_signin_btn_text_dark;
common_signin_btn_text_light;

Answer (score 0):

@ugur error tells you what is missing as its not in your supplied file list, so you have to put that file in the drawable folder to remove the error..once you add he banner drawable the error will go away

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question in this link but this didn't work for me:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/935508/failed-to-re-package-resources-unity-5.html?sort=oldest

For me changing the AndroidManifest.xml with the following did the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.example.admobtest" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <!-- Google Mobile Ads Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <!-- meta-data tag for Google Play services -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: What lines did you change?

Answer (score 0):

I had banner.png at correct place and rest of the things were also ok.
It worked when I updated sdk to latest with help of "SDK Manager"